# PDFMergerUtility append new string

Tags: java, pdf

I use at present the library PDFMergerUtility, to merge PDF between them. I would like to put between the various PDF, the page with the text.
- > my PDF (File)
- > my text (String)
- > my PDF (File)

However I do not manage to add a page with the text without creating a PDF page in my file, then deleting it.

An idea?

Comment: Have you tried creating a PDF with one page (in memory or temporary file) and then append it inbetween two PDF?

Comment: exactly tried? or exactly the solution?

Comment: It is for what I try to make but for what unfortunately I do not arrive has to make

Comment: You might want to show the code of your attempt so people can tell you how to improve it.